# pyserial write function blocks without writing data and does not time out

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

I am using python 2.7, pyserial for 2.7, and on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2

When I execute the code:

```
connection.write(b'{}'.format(deviceData[deviceType][STATUSREQ]))
```

the program hangs forever until interrupted by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, which in turn reveals that a line of code in */serial/serialposix.py* is becoming "stuck" (since it is always at this line when the program is killed)...

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 511, in write
    _, ready, _ = select.select([], [self.fd], [], None)
```

Previously, I was running this code on an older model Raspberry Pi (B) and did not encounter this issue.

I have tried unplugging everything from the pins and the issue still occurs.  Using an oscilloscope, I have been able to determine that the data to be sent ("\xf0\xff") is never sent from the Pi's Tx pin(8) when the write function is reached.

Comment: Are you sure you're writing to the correct serial port (i.e. `'/dev/ttyUSB0'`)?  It can change when you plug in different devices and even if you unplug and replug in the same device.

Comment: I have been using /dev/ttyAMA0 (since I'm sending/receiving through the Tx/Rx UART pins) but I believe it is still sending to this port unless something mysterious is occurring.

[code]serialport = serial.Serial (port="/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=0.01)[/code]

Comment: Assuming that it were sending to the wrong port, would that not just result in missed data as opposed to causing the function to block?

Comment: Ah, I just realized the Pi 3's port names might be different than the B's...I'll look into that.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  ttyAMA0 was reassigned to Bluetooth on Pi 3, and ttyS0 was assigned to the UART pins.  Thanks!  If you want to add your suggestion as an answer I can accept it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably writing to the wrong serial port, which can change depending on the device, or even just when disconnecting and reconnecting a device.